# React lazy component for specific environment

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, create-react-app

I did successfully implement a lazy loaded component in a CRA generated React application.

As said component is shown only in development environment, is there a way - without ejecting - to avoid its specific chunk to be present in a production build?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use environment variables:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  return (<YourComponent />)
}
```

Comment: That's the logic to conditionally show the component, and it works fine.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to mark the lazy import:
`const DebugView = React.lazy(() => import('./component/debugView/debugView.component'));`
so that when i build the project for production the relevant .js chunk is not exported